# Three-level analog output (Ground, 2.5V and 5V) - DAC good enough?

Tags: analog

I'm planning to replace the thermostat of my evaporative cooler with a Raspberry Pi plus some control (see [Wiring a 24-volt Swamp (Evaporative) Cooler for Control With Relays](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/80268/wiring-a-24-volt-swamp-evaporative-cooler-for-control-with-relays)).  Signaling from the current thermostat to the control panel is done using DC signaling at Ground, 2-3V and 4-5V.  How can I create these three logic levels with the least amount of circuitry required?  Precision is very low (see the +/- 0.5V ranges), but I don't know how much current the cooler control panel will draw on these DC lines so not sure if a simple DAC will be sufficient.

Comment: I'd say a DAC (as in a chip) would be overkill.  What's wrong with a few resistors powered from the 5V and switched in/out with a MOSFET or two?

Comment: I'd use two output bits, and some resistors and transistors, to produce the required voltages.  The exact circuit configuration will depend on the input characteristics of the control panel: does it sink or source current, and if so, how much, or is it a high-impedance voltage sensor, or ??

Answer (score 2):

Try this circuit:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgPKZ3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

B high (A don't care)- 0V out
B low, A high - 2~3V out
B low, A low - 4~5V out

Since the RPi has 0V/3.3V out, we need to shift the levels up to get 5V out, and 
the transistors are a pretty good way of doing that. R1 (1/4W) makes it short-circuit
proof, R6/R7 establish the voltages, R8 R9 just limit the base current.